# Different databases for collections in NodeJS/MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoengine, node-mongodb-native

In a project I am using [node-mongodb-native](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) to connect to a database with some collections.

Now there's another database containing one other collection needed. I want to query this collection from the same project, with the minimum amount of code change.

I know [MongoEngine does this](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/connecting.html?highlight=db_alias#multiple-databases) rather pretty.

Is there a standard way of doing this in NodeJS, e.g. with the node-mongodb-native driver?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is the way you are connecting to the mongo DB, Similarly you can create a new Mongo client variable with a different name to connect to the new db.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
  , assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject';
// Use connect method to connect to the Server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected correctly to server");

  insertDocuments(db, function() {
    db.close();
  });
});
```